# Failing to use $PWD with sed, bash

Tags: bash, path, sed, pwd

I am trying to create a script that replaces sub strings with an absolute path, so I'm using

```
sed s/TEMPDIR/$PWD/ file.py > newfile.py
```

So obviously I want to replace TEMP with the absolute path, but I keep getting

> sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'

I think it might be because the path contains '/', but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Also, deos PWD guaranties an absolute path, given that I don't deal with links?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use a different delimiter:

```
sed "s@TEMPDIR@$PWD@" file.py > newfile.py
```

Using PWD probably does not guarantee an absolute path.  (Depends on the shell).   But `pwd` will return an absolute path, so use:

```
sed "s@TEMPDIR@$(pwd)@" file.py > newfile.py
```

Note that neither of these will work if your paths contain `@`.  Pick a delimiter that does not appear in either.   Note the following from the shell standard:

*In cases where PWD is set to the pathname that would be output by pwd -P, if there is insufficient permission on the current working directory, or on any parent of that directory, to determine what that pathname would be, the value of PWD is unspecified. Assignments to this variable may be ignored. If an application sets or unsets the value of PWD , the behaviors of the cd and pwd utilities are unspecified.*

So you can probably rely on $PWD.  Note that neither `pwd` nor `$PWD` will resolve symbolic links, so you might prefer to use `readlink -f .`

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Also, if the old file is the same as the new file, I get a blank file. Any ideas why? And again, thanks

Comment: In the shell `cmd file > file` will always result in `file` being empty, no matter what the cmd is.  The shell truncates `file` before it even attempts to parse `cmd`.